# How do I get the root display object of a MovieClip to be a MovieClip object with Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, mxml

I am trying to build an MXML application with Flash Builder 4.5, and I am integrating an API that requires the root of a display object to be a MovieClip. Personally I think this is bad design but I have to go with it. The root object always seems to end up as the stage, because of course I have to add the object to the stage for it to be added to the display list. Is there some way that I can either change the stage type in an MXML application to a MovieClip or is there some way to force a MovieClip wrapper to become the root of a display object?

Comment: AFAIK, Flex application is already a movie clip. The first frame is the preloader part, the second frame is the application itself.

Comment: maybe you are looking for  FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication

Comment: @Hrundik I think that if you export an application from flash for flex it is wrapped in something called a UIMovieClip.


@Yordan Yanakiev could you elaborate on this?


I believe what I need to do is set an application container that is of type MovieClip but I am unsure of how to do this.

Comment: @me232 then I don't get you. Do you want to load movie clips into your flex application, or do you want to load your flex application to some other place that expects MovieClip?

Comment: @Flextras.com The root of the .swf generated by mxmlc for your application is a generated class which extends SystemManager. And SystemManager is inherited from MovieClip. So, you can load your flex application using loader:Loader, you can cast loader.content as MovieClip safely.

Comment: How about you tell us why you need the root to be a MovieClip?  Ever thought of just having the loaded SWF just be self contained within the loader?

Comment: I am working with an API and it looks to be badly coded. It provides you with a movie clip that is used by the API, but it also makes reference to its root display object, which it expects to be a movieclip itself. I have found that I can get this to work by wrapping the API movieclip in a UIComponent and adding to the application via `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplicaton.addElement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both mx Application and Spark Application inherit from Sprite, not MovieClip.  Take a look at the inheritance chain at the top of

> [mx Application docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html)
>
> [Spark Application docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html)

The third-party API can't cast your Flex movie to MovieClip, because it's not one.

HTH;

aMY